# C# Compare two comboxBox values and remove duplicate values

Tags: c#, combobox, compare, duplicates

I have two comboBoxes which have some duplicate values, my problem is I need to compare tow comboBoxes and need to remove duplicate values in comboBox 1 only, here is a code which express how to remove duplicates in comparing one comboBox value. Please support me.

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(i => i.ItemArray[0]).Distinct().ToArray());

DataTable table = new DataTable();
{
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select LorryNo from Table1", cs))
da.Fill(table);
}
cs.Open();
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "LorryNo";
cs.Close();

DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
{
using (SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select LorryNo from Table2", cs))
da2.Fill(table2);
}
cs.Open();
comboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "LorryNo";
cs.Close();
```

Comment: What is the data binding for the second combo box?

Comment: Ya, use databinding create two lists and bind to view. That way you can use linq like this: listA.Except(listB)

Comment: Thanks for the reply gentlemen, like as following I'm binding: comboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
 comboBox2.DisplayMember = "LorryNo";

Comment: Can you able to provide sample coding?

Comment: Can you? Can you put all the relevant code? like what is table? Why does table have values and then you have another list of other values? Why not bind to that table? or clone the table based on a set of conditions? Or spawn your lists off a set of conditions and make your distinction there. There are too many factors about how you are implementing this to give an answer or feedback with what's been supplied.

Comment: Ok alykins, I have mentioned my code above, I'll explain what I need to do. According to above coding, I'm getting results to two combo boxes, for example if value 001 available in both combo boxes, I need to remove it from both combo boxes, other should be remain. This is only I need.

Comment: Ok cool- makes a lot more sense now looking at it- thank you. Question on your database... Are there relationships set up between Table1 and Table2? If this were me I would modify my select queries to select from table1 join on table2 where value doesn't exist... Fix it on your population of data. Is that a viable option for you?

Comment: Great advise alykins, I modified the sql query as follows, now it's working..... Thanks a lot..... "select distinct t1.LorryNo from Table1 t1, Table2 l
where t1.LorryNo!=t2.LorryNo"

Comment: Awesome :) glad you got it working